# ZAKAAT divided for husband and wife

Tags: zakat

IF a girl own 14 tola gold and she give 7 tola to her husband. Now they own 7 tola each should they still pay zakaat on it? or is this right or wrong?

Comment: Zakaat should take into account the situation where you live. For example, if the country is not a tyranny, and you pay taxes some of which goes on social services - this should, in some way, go towards discharging the obligation of Zakaat.

Answer (score 0):

7 tola ( 70 grams) falls under Nisab so yes, that is less than what obligates Zakat but you have to consider other assets  which you have to pay zakat for